# How to break a long line when using SyntaxHighlighter?

Tags: html, css, syntax-highlighting

I have my CSS code below:

```
pre,code{ 
white-space:pre-wrap;/*css-3*/ 
white-space:-moz-pre-wrap;/*Mozilla,since1999*/ 
white-space:-pre-wrap;/*Opera4-6*/ 
white-space:-o-pre-wrap;/*Opera7*/ 
word-wrap:break-word;/*InternetExplorer5.5+*/　　
}
```

but in the page http://www.51ojr.com/report/full/81 . 
line 21 in the source code part at the bottom page need to breark-line. 
But the result is that it cannot break one long line into tow lines, why?

Comment: Which line is the one that needs breaking?

Comment: line 21 of the source code